# Disable internet access to untrusted devices?

Tags: networking, router, dmz

I have a few devices in my network which have outdated firmware and I would like to make sure that they cannot communicate with the Internet.

My plan is to include a second router and build a DMZ-like environment:

[image: Diagram]

So I would have two subnets:

- 192.168.170.0/24 for the devices that have Internet access
- 192.168.180.0/24 which may not communicate with the Internet (nor in or out!), but they may fully communicate with the other devices

I have a few questions about this setup:

1. Is it good or is there a better solution?
2. Which kind of 2nd-router should I choose, maybe something simple as a Raspberry Router with two NICs?
3. What do I need to do in order to block Internet access (IN and OUT) on the second router? The default gateway would be 192.168.180.1, and this gateway knows 192.168.170.1/24, but since 192.168.170.1 knows the WAN, their default gateway is also known to the untrusted network?? I would like to have full communication with 192.168.170.1/24, but no IN/OUT communication with WAN.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: ok, you mention "DMZ-like" network, and unsolicited Internet Ingress to those devices. your gateway router is a NAT box, right? do you really want to allow unsolicited ingress traffic to ANY of your devices? the simplest answer, would be to block egress traffic originating from the devices on the vodaphone box. There shouldn't be a need to explicitly block ingress traffic to them, unless you allow UPNP. Don't get me wrong, your idea has merit if you want to spend the money to expand the network, but it does introduce additional complexity, and you are not using enterprise grade hardware.

Comment: if you don't have control over the vodaphone box, or it lacks basic features, consider placing your new router between it and All of your devices instead. then your whole network could benefit from the additional features. the only potential issue there is if you use wifi provisioned on the ISP box. you would have to implement wifi from within the network, on your new router, or with an AP.

Comment: @FrankThomas I mentioned "DMZ like" because I know that DMZ contains two routers. But actually, I do NOT want a DMZ (i.e. exposing the devices to the WAN). The trusted devices should stay protected behind a NAT router, like they are now. The change in the network should be the introduction of Router #2 and then move the untrusted devices from network #1 to network #2. The other computers stay in network #1

Comment: @FrankThomas If I place Router #2 between the Vodafone box and all other devices, then the untrusted devices and trusted devices share the same gateway, and that means they can access the Internet, or am I wrong? (I would also like to block outgoing Internet access, because I know that the old/untrusted NAS calls home to a Command-and-Control server owned by the vendor, which is horrible)

Comment: I'm saying you likely already have a firewall on the vodaphone box, that you could use to block outgoing connections from the IPs of the outdated devices.youd have to do this either way regardless of how many routers. if you install an additional router, you would just use its firewall to block requests from the old devices. since you are behind NAT, unsolicited traffic from the outside can't reach your devices, so the only option an adversary would have would be to exploit a connection established from the bad device. if you block its network traffic, then that is no longer a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good or is there a better solution?

It's a possible solution, but as your threat model is "outdated devices shouldn't communicate with the internet" and not "outdated devices should be isolated in a DMZ, because they might take over other devices", it's a bit overkill.

An alternative would be to keep them all in a single segment, which will avoid disvocery and routing headaches, and things like printers not working if they rely on broadcast protocols, and use an IP-based filter in your main router.

In principle, any Linux-based router will offer this possibility, but your Vodafone box may or may not expose it through an UI, and you may or may not be able to replace the firmware on the Vodafone router.

> Which kind of 2nd-router should I choose

Any kind of router that either has a firmware where you can configure the necessary filters, or where you can install an open firmware like OpenWRT. For the latter, there are many cheap options.

> What do I need to do in order to block Internet access (IN and OUT) on the second router?

Set up firewall tables. [Here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_configuration) are the docs for OpenWRT, if you want to use existing firmware it depends on the firmware.

In general, you want to configure routing properly, and you want to block any outgoing connections from the DMZ to anything not in the "trusted devices" segment.